# Filtring array with custom objects

Tags: ios, iphone, arrays

I want to filter an array from another array which contain custom objects. 
Below example of dictionary.

NSArray *ContactsArray = [mainArray valueForKey:@"phoneNumber"];

I have tried with

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"phoneNumber IN %@",mainArray];

NSArray *ContactsArray = [array2 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: please see this link, i hope this will help you... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810365/filter-nsarray-based-on-another-array-using-predicate