# ios How to filter two array using predicate on an object property

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
@interface MemberModel : NSObject
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *name; //名字
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *code; //编码
@property(nonatomic,copy)NSString *avatarUrl; //头像
@end

MemberModel *model1 = [MemberModel New];
MemberModel *model2 = [MemberModel New];
MemberModel *model3 = [MemberModel New];
model1.name = @"J";
model2.name = @"JJ"
model2.name = @"JJJ"
NSArray *array1 = @[model1,model2,model3];

MemberModel *model4 = [MemberModel New];
MemberModel *model5 = [MemberModel New];
MemberModel *model6 = [MemberModel New];
model4.name = @"Jj";
model5.name = @"JJ"
model6.name = @"JJ11J"
NSArray *array2 = @[model4,model5,model6];
```

I want to filter of the same model's name in the two array
this is my code:

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (self.name IN %@)", [array2 valueForKey:@"name"]];
NSArray *source = [array1 filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

but not use , please tell me how to solve ， thanks

Comment: It is not what I want

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810365/filter-nsarray-based-on-another-array-using-predicate .. **Please read** http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . It is hard for people to understand what you want. All you said is "I want to filter of the same model's name in the two array this is my code but not use"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27810365/filter-nsarray-based-on-another-array-using-predicate this answer help me ,thank u